# Identifying Replacement Parts for My Bathtub

Tags: plumbing, repair, faucet, bathtub

[image]

I need to identify what parts I need to buy to replace this.
We can't even shower its completly stripped

Comment: From your limited information in question, guessing that is the diverter valve for the shower.  Will need to know the make of shower or take it to hardware or plumbing store.

Comment: Is that the hot side? Is the cold in better shape, where we could see the handle in a pic?

Comment: Yeah you should include an overall pic so we have an idea what's going on.  That looks like a spout on the bottom right and the part you're looking at is the hot water valve.  Picture could be better, but it looks damaged.  Some shower parts can be replaced many times, but if a crucial part that can't be removed from the front is damaged, you'll have to open the wall to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those projects that you need to turn the water off, if just hot make sure no one turns another faucet on with cold and hot or water will come out once the valve stem is removed.

Remove the trim
There should be a nut remove the nut (it’s called the packing nut)

The valve body may come out with the nut

If the valve body stays turn the stem and remove

Take that assembly to a local plumbing store.
Match up the assembly.

If it has a rubber washer seal seat get one for the new valve and one for the cold they are cheap,,  buy a box of them then when the new faucet gets hard to turn off you change the washer, seat/seal or whatever you want to call it (it looks like a little round volcano when new when worn out it looks like a flat o ring held in by a brass screw.

Install the new valve with a new washer/seal, seat.
Natal the packing nut there is usually a seal here also
The packing is many times a PFTE string or cord it may be white or black impregnated with graphite.
The PFTE is wrapped around the shaft and the packing nut compresses the seal so it won’t leak.

Replace the trim

Turn water on and verify no leaks. And the valve works.